# Is it possible to use a inverse distance transform?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an input depth image of rocks which I have to segment. I have found a good way to detect the edges. I want to apply the Watershed Algorithm to segment the rocks. I need to apply the distance transform now to know the distance to the edges. But the results are not as expected.

I tried various other options provided by opencv including CV_DIST_FAIR, CV_DIST_WELSCH.

But I need something of an inverse to the distance transform which shows highest intensity within the rocks. I can use this then as markers.

```
// Tried to inverse the binary but that doesn't work
//cv::bitwise_not(cannyedge_detected_image, cannyedge_detected_image);

// Finding the distance to the boundaries
cv::Mat distance_transformed_image, dst_distance_transform;
cv::distanceTransform(cannyedge_detected_image, distance_transformed_image, CV_DIST_L2, 3);
cv::normalize(distance_transformed_image, distance_transformed_image, 0, 1., cv::NORM_MINMAX);
cv::resize(distance_transformed_image, dst_distance_transform, cv::Size(image.cols * 3, image.rows * 3));
cv::imshow("Distance Transform", dst_distance_transform);
cv::waitKey(200);
```

The results look like :
[image]

Comment: distance transform unintuitively needs the edges to be black and the background to be white, afair. So just invert the input mask.

Comment: @Micka: thank you for your reply.  do you mean to use a cv::bitwise_not before the distance transform? If yes, i tried it and it did not work out

Comment: if your mat is 8 bit, just use 255-value to invert

Comment: then won't the background also be affected? I don't want to affect the background.
Note : The background is the black part in the Original Depth Image

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve, distance transform will compute the distance to the nearest 0 value pixel